$\binom{2n}{n}$ is the number of length $2n$ words over $\{A,B\}$ such that going from left to right, there're never more $B$s than $A$s at any point
According to Wikipedia, $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the number of words of length $2n$ made up of $A$ and $B$ within which, as one reads from left to right, there are never more $B$'s than $A$'s at any point.
How can this be proved?

Hint: If it consists of $n+t$ B's and $n-t$ A's, then the number of arrangements is $\binom {2n}{n+t}-\binom{2n}{n+t+1}$.

Credit goes to @JetfiRex for the hint.
Let $N(n,t)$ be the number of length $2n$ words over $\{A,B\}$ consisting of $n+t$ $A$'s and $n-t$ $B$'s, within which, as one reads from left to right, there are never more $B$'s than $A$'s at any point.
Clearly $N(n,n)=1$.
For any $0\le t\lt n$, let $X_t$ be the set of length $2n$ words over $\{A,B\}$ consisting of $n+t$ $A$'s and $n-t$ $B$'s.
For any $w\in X_t$, we call $w$ good if as one reads $w$ from left to right, there are never more $B$'s than $A$'s at any point and bad otherwise.
Suppose $w$ is bad. Then there exists a position such that there are more $B$'s than $A$'s. Let $k$ be the smallest such position. Flips all the letters whose positions are not larger than $k$ to create a word $v$. Note that $v$ consists of $n+t+1$ $A$'s and $n-t-1$ $B$'s. This establishes a one-to-one correspondence between the set of bad words in $X_t$ and the set of words over $\{A,B\}$ consisting of $n+t+1$ $A$'s and $n-t-1$ $B$'s. Therefore $N(n,t)=\binom{(n+t)+(n-t)}{n+t}-\binom{(n+t+1)+(n-t-1)}{n+t+1}=\binom{2n}{n+t}-\binom{2n}{n+t+1}$.
Hence the number of words of length $2n$ made up of $A$ and $B$ within which, as one reads from left to right, there are never more $B$'s than $A$'s at any point is given by $1+\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}(\binom{2n}{n+t}-\binom{2n}{n+t+1})=\binom{2n}{n}$.

If you are familiar with Catalan numbers  then you can prove this by induction.
It boils down to proving that:$$2C_n+4\left[\binom{2n}{n}-C_n\right]=\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\tag1$$where $C_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan number, i.e.  $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$.
This number $C_n$ equals the number of words of length $2n$ that satisfy the condition mentioned by you and next to that satisfy the extra condition that the numbers of A's and B's in it are both $n$.
Proving $(1)$ is just routine.
